# Package selinput Error: Cannot find a matching encoding

Tags: moderncv, french

I am trying to write a CV in French using `moderncv` package, and every time I compile the file it gives me the following error: `Package selinput Error: Cannot find a matching encoding`. Here is the code I'm using:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,french]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{banking} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{%
 adieresis={ä},
 eacute={é},
 Lcaron={Ľ},
}
\firstname{Ahmed} 
\familyname{Maanan} 

\title{CV}
\address{1145 Rue Bouregreg}{Hay Salam, Salé}
\mobile{(+212) 0699779383}
\phone{(+212) 0537804664}

\email{}


%\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{600k.eps} % The first bracket is the picture height, the second is the thickness of the frame around the picture (0pt for no frame)


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Formation}

\cventry{2013--2014}{Baccalauréat}{Lycée Hassan II - Rabat}{}{\textit{}}{Lettres et Sciences Humaines - Branche Lettres}  % Arguments not required can be left empty



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Expérience Professionnelle}



\cventry{Août 2016 -- Avril 2017}{Gérant}{\textsc{Snack Chhiwa}}{Salé}{}{} 
%\begin{itemize}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Accueil de la clientèle
        \item Gestion des stocks
        \item Choix des produits
        \item Encadrement du personnel
        \item Tenue de la caisse
    \end{itemize}
%\end{itemize}


\cventry{Août 2015 -- Juillet 2016}{Gérant}{\textsc{Cybercafé Le Petit Bleu}}{Salé}{}{}
%\begin{itemize}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Assurer l'ordre et la propreté du Cybercafé
        \item Traitement de texte
        \item Gravure, fax, scanner, impression et photocopie
        \item Maintenance du matériel informatique
        \item Tenue de la caisse
    \end{itemize}
%\end{itemize}


\cventry{Juillet 2014 -- Juillet 2015}{Gérant}{\textsc{Télé-boutique}}{Salé}{}{}
%\begin{itemize}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Assurer l'ordre et la propreté de la Télé-boutique
        \item Vente de cartes de recharge, journaux et documents administratifs
        \item Traitement de texte
        \item Photocopie et impression
        \item Tenue de la caisse
    \end{itemize}
%\end{itemize}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMPUTER SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Compétences Informatiques}

\cvitem{Systèmes d'exploitation}{Windows, Linux, Mac OS X}
\cvitem{Bureautique}{Microsoft Office, Latex, Adobe Acrobat XI Pro}
\cvitem{Base de données}{Microsoft Access, MySQL, Oracle RDBMS}
\cvitem{Image}{Photoshop CS, InDesign CS, Illustrator CS, Inkscape}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMMUNICATION SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Vie Associative }

\cventry{2012 -- 2015}{Membre}{\textsc{Association Al-Rissala}}{Salé}{}{}
%\begin{itemize}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Organisation logistique et animation de manifestations caritatives
        \item Participation à la collecte de fonds
        \item Encadrement de jeunes bénévoles
    \end{itemize}
%\end{itemize}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LANGUAGES SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Compétences Linguistiques}


\cvitemwithcomment{Arabe}{Langue maternelle}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Français}{Courant}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Amazigh}{Courant}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Anglais}{Courant}{}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTERESTS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Centres d'Intérêt}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~} % Changes the symbol used for lists

\cvlistdoubleitem{Lecture}{Vélo}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Bricolage}{Arts Martiaux}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: selinput tries to guess the input encoding but you have already done `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` just do one or the other. If you know your file is in utf8 then do not use `selinput` if you do not know what encoding it is in then don't use `inputenc` let `selinput ` guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write an cv in frensh with `moderncv` use the following MWE.

In your case you need not to use `selinput`. Better use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and package `babel` with `\usepackage{babel}`. Do not forget to save your `tex` code with code encription `utf8`!

The MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,french]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{banking} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % <=========================================
\usepackage{babel} % <==================================================

\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\firstname{Ahmed} 
\familyname{Maanan} 

\title{CV}
\address{1145 Rue Bouregreg}{Hay Salam, Salé}
\mobile{(+212) 0699779383}
\phone{(+212) 0537804664}

\email{}

%\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{600k.eps} % The first bracket is the picture height, the second is the thickness of the frame around the picture (0pt for no frame)


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title


\section{Formation}

\cventry{2013--2014}{Baccalauréat}{Lycée Hassan II - Rabat}{}{\textit{}}{Lettres et Sciences Humaines - Branche Lettres}  % Arguments not required can be left empty


\section{Expérience Professionnelle}

\cventry{Août 2016 -- Avril 2017}{Gérant}{\textsc{Snack Chhiwa}}{Salé}{}{} 
\begin{itemize}
  \item Accueil de la clientèle
  \item Gestion des stocks
  \item Choix des produits
  \item Encadrement du personnel
  \item Tenue de la caisse
\end{itemize}

\cventry{Août 2015 -- Juillet 2016}{Gérant}{\textsc{Cybercafé Le Petit Bleu}}{Salé}{}{}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Assurer l'ordre et la propreté du Cybercafé
  \item Traitement de texte
  \item Gravure, fax, scanner, impression et photocopie
  \item Maintenance du matériel informatique
  \item Tenue de la caisse
\end{itemize}

\cventry{Juillet 2014 -- Juillet 2015}{Gérant}{\textsc{Télé-boutique}}{Salé}{}{}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Assurer l'ordre et la propreté de la Télé-boutique
  \item Vente de cartes de recharge, journaux et documents administratifs
  \item Traitement de texte
  \item Photocopie et impression
  \item Tenue de la caisse
\end{itemize}


\section{Compétences Informatiques}

\cvitem{Systèmes d'exploitation}{Windows, Linux, Mac OS X}
\cvitem{Bureautique}{Microsoft Office, Latex, Adobe Acrobat XI Pro}
\cvitem{Base de données}{Microsoft Access, MySQL, Oracle RDBMS}
\cvitem{Image}{Photoshop CS, InDesign CS, Illustrator CS, Inkscape}


\section{Vie Associative }

\cventry{2012 -- 2015}{Membre}{\textsc{Association Al-Rissala}}{Salé}{}{}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Organisation logistique et animation de manifestations caritatives
  \item Participation à la collecte de fonds
  \item Encadrement de jeunes bénévoles
\end{itemize}


\section{Compétences Linguistiques}

\cvitemwithcomment{Arabe}{Langue maternelle}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Français}{Courant}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Amazigh}{Courant}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Anglais}{Courant}{}


\section{Centres d'Intérêt}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~} % Changes the symbol used for lists

\cvlistdoubleitem{Lecture}{Vélo}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Bricolage}{Arts Martiaux}
\end{document}
```

compiles without errors to the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Remark: For me it seems that you have saved your TeX code not in `utf8` encoding. I can recreate your error if I run your code with for example `ansi` encoding. Because french uses a lot of accents etc. it is better to use `utf8` as I showed in my MWE ...